# Performing 128 bit math in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

We need a way to do 128 bit math in a Node.js program.  It looks like I can link a C++ library to do this, but since this will be open source for many platforms I would first like to try something that would not introduce special platform builds.

I see that JavaScript only supports only up to 64-bits.  However, I have also seen JavaScript emulate a CPU and run Linux, so I'm certain this is possible.  I'm not certain yet, but we probably need only a few basic math functions.

Do you know of something that exists already (I have not found one)?  What approach would you take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
npm install int
```

and see if that works for you -- it is supposedly handling arbitrary precision integer

documentation here; https://www.npmjs.org/package/int

There is list of similar packages if that specific package does not work for you; https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/bignum

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:

```
npm install big.js
```

It claims to be a small, fast JavaScript library for arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic.

[Try this.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/big.js)

Answer (score 2):

### News from the year 2020:

Node.js (version 10.4.0+) supports BigInts, which are arbitrarily large **integers**.

- They can be created by appending an `n` to a number, or by calling `BigInt()`, for example

  - `123n`
  - `BigInt(123)`
- Operators `+, *, -, /, **, %` work as with numbers
- Operator `/` **truncates** the result to an integer
- Operators `<<, >>, <<<` work as with numbers
- Operator `>>>` **does not** work
- `123n == 123`, but `123n !== 123` (they are different types)

For more information see:
[MDN web docs BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: This isnt a constructor. so we cant use `new` here. Just use BigInt(123)